# Does a system of linear equation "equal " to a matrix equation or it is just a trick to solve these equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does a system of linear equation "equal" to a matrix form Ax=b or it is not equal(as if it just a "trick" to solve system of linear equation)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you meant by 'equal' in quotes? Maybe 'equivalent'?

Comment: I mean how a matrix represent an equation ?Matrix is just a array of number but equation relate a quantity left side to other quantity in right side.

Comment: Absaed, see the answer below. Obviously, matrix alone is not enough to represent an equation. You also need a columb vector of unknowns and the column vector on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix form just puts the left and right hand sides of the equations into matrices. Each row represents one of the equations. The matrix equation is just another way to represent the system of equations. For example, if you have the equations $$2x+3y=9$$
$$x-2y=6$$

These are identical (enclosing each side of the equations in parantheses) to the matrix form:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2x+3y\\ x-2y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 9\\ 6\end{pmatrix}$$

which we can also write in the form $Ax=b$ as:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 &3\\ 1 &-2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 9\\ 6\end{pmatrix}.$$

We can easily go back from this matrix form to the original equations. In this sense the two representations are equivalent.